# Input onChange and useState for keeping amount multiple products is not working great

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no short description for this issue, but i'll try to explain myself:

I have a Webshop React project. In this project I have a page which contains products (which are components itself). The idea was to have a small 2-digit input field for each component where you can type in the amount you would like to order from that item.

When you type in an amount I want to keep the state of every change. So onChange made sence to me. When I looked up how other people did this, I found almost every same way with also the onChange event.

But this way gives a bad user experience. When I type the first character it offcourse triggers the onChange event, which gives an update to the 'amountItems' state i made up, which gives the value back to the input. As a result, the second character can't be typed, because the value is updated. As this is a controlled component, I need to give it a value (leaving the value option out, gives a blank input when you type)

So what I have now:

```
/..........
                                <div className="productOrder">
                                    <form onSubmit={AddToCart} method="POST">
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            placeholder=""
                                            maxLength="2"
                                            name={product_name}
                                            value={current_value}                                      
                                            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                                        />

                                        <Button value="Order" usage="buttonCheckout" name="cart" type="cart"/>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
/............
```

The handleChange updates the amountItems as all will be pushed to the shoppingcart:

```
  function handleChange(evt) {

        const value = evt.target.value;

        setAmountItem({
            ...amountItem,
            [evt.target.name]: value,
        });
    }
```

When i console.log the state, the items are updated. It's just a annoying effect, which you can only be avoided by typing really fast, else you will have to focus the field again to type. I looked for some kind of timeout function for this, but none were working correctly.

What is a good way to handle this? Maybe I need a refactor on this whole thing?

Comment: Your answer: `maxLength=2`. Delete this question.

Comment: @Adam yeah, I was afraid of that, because all the answers I found have the same way of managing an onChange. Still, the only way to get normal typing is when I remove the 'onChange' event. When I try the code on this stackblitz with only 1 named item, it works as it should. WHen I put the input at App.js, the same as in Stackblitz, it works. 

The path: App > (components) Products > Product. App & products dont give a issue. But the product.js does. And disabling every css/component/layout doesn't work. Even when i hard code "item_1". I dont get it.

Comment: Removing maxLength is not the solution (and yes, I tried).  It want to give it max 2 chars. I did the same code on SB. It works there.

Comment: omg.... I wanted a real unique child key instead of index.

The problem was this: <div key={uuidv4()} className="Product">

This makes it owns call :/ How stupid....